# Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil

Tags: swift

```
func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage {

    let memeImage = imageView.image!
    let newImageViewOriginAndDimension = self.view.frame
    let originalImageViewOriginAndDimension = imageView.frame
    rescaleImageView(newImageViewOriginAndDimension, image: memeImage)
    print(imageView.frame) // has fatal error unexpectedly found nil
    // other unrelated lines of code
}
func rescaleImageView(originAndDimension: CGRect, image : UIImage) {
    let newImageView : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: originAndDimension)
    newImageView.image = image
    imageView = newImageView
    print(imageView.frame) // prints fine
}
```

So I have two functions above can someone explain to me why I am able to run execute `print(imageView.frame)` without error in the function `rescaleImageView` but not in the `generateMemedImage` function?

Am I correct to assume that when I create the `newImageView` in my `generateMemedImage` function I'm not actually assigning the `imageView` variable in my class to `newImageView` but rather just reassigning the pointer locally in my function?

Comment: How is the `imageView` property declared? Is it `weak` or `unowned` by any chance?

Comment: Yeah it is weak, oh right is it because when I reassign it the moment of reference deallocates the pointer to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a newly created `newImageView` into a `weak` property. Thats why it is not alive in the first method scope. It was simply deallocated. It works in the second method because the object is retained by `newImageView` constant. You are not adding the new view to a superview, thus it will not be retained (nor you are removing the old one). But creating a new `UIImageView` doesn't make sense in your case. All you have to do is to assign your image to the existing view. Like following:

```
func rescaleImageView(originAndDimension: CGRect, image : UIImage) {
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.frame = originAndDimension
}
```